# MySQL: Update several entries with array values in 1 call?

Tags: php, mysql

If I have a table in a MySQL DB, with fields **id** and **position** amung others.

Then in PHP I have an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 3
    [2] => 8
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 5
    [5] => 6
    [6] => 7
)
```

Where the array key should map to the position and the array value should map to the id.

For example, If I made a call for every array value the first would be

```
UPDATE table SET position = 0 WHERE id = 1
```

Is there a way I could do all this in 1 call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$string = "";
foreach($array as $k => $v)
 $string .= "UPDATE table SET position = ".$v." WHERE id = ".$k.";";
mysql_query($string);
```

Comment: it make only 1 request to DB, this code simply loop through the array and create a string composed by more concatenate queries...

Comment: No! It only makes one call because the foreach has no brackets!

Comment: MySQL's PHP driver does not allow more than one query statement in any given query call. This construct will fail with a syntax error.

Comment: However this is not going to work this way cause you cannot include multiple statements at once using ; also += should change to .= because += is mathematical operation not string conncatenation.

Answer (score 1):

updating multiple records with different values for each record is possible, but it's not recommdned - it makes for an incredibly ugly query:

```
UPDATE table
SET position = CASE position
    WHEN 0 THEN 1
    WHEN 1 THEN 3
    WHEN 2 THEN 8
    etc...
```

Comment: this sound very interesting. I am interested to know is there any other reason this is not recommended apart from being ugly?

Answer (score 0):

Here we go a foreach solution :

```
$Array = array(0 => 1, 1 => 3);

if(count($Array) > 0){
    foreach($Array as $Key => $Value)
        // UPDATE table SET position = 1 WHERE id = 3 LIMIT 1
        mysql_query('UPDATE table SET position = '.$Key.' WHERE id = '.$Value.' LIMIT 1;');
}
```

Problem : you can't do multiple update with MySQL ... yes, like Marc B said but it's very ugly.